# Добавить ng-click через метод директивы compile

Tags: angularjs

Добрый день.
У меня есть директива

```
<hierarchy-tree tree-object-func="todoTreeFunc()">
</hierarchy-tree>
```

и она создает внутри себя разметку, на выходе получается

```
<hierarchy-tree tree-object-func="todoTreeFunc()">
  <div>Element 1</div>
  <div>Element 2</div>
</hierarchy-tree>
```

Теперь я хочу в созданные блоки добавить `ng-click` что бы получилось

```
<hierarchy-tree tree-object-func="todoTreeFunc()">
  <div ng-click="myFunc($event)">Element 1</div>
  <div ng-click="myFunc($event)">Element 2</div>
</hierarchy-tree>
```

У этой директивы есть контроллер, а добавление `ng-click` я выполняю в методе `compile`, выглядит так

```
        controller: function($scope) {
            $scope.openEntityPage = function(event) {
                console.log('click', event);
            };
        },
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
            return {
                pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {
                    iElement.attr('ng-click', 'openEntityPage()')
                },
                post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, ctrl) {}
            }
        }
```

Но `ng-click` не работает, хотя я добавил когда образуется шаблон директивы на ствдии `compile`.
Почему не работает `ng-click` и как его исправить??
Спасибо.

```js
angular.module('hierarchyTree')
    .directive('hierarchyTree', function() {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                treeObjectFunc: '&'
            },
            controller: function($scope) {
                $scope.allProjects = [{
                    name: 'Project 1',
                    childs: [{
                        name: 'Task 1',
                        childs: [{
                            name: 'Task 1.1' 
                        }, {
                            name: 'Task 1.2' 
                        }] 
                    }, {
                        name: 'Task 2' 
                    }, {
                        name: 'Task 3' 
                    }] 
                }, {
                    name: 'Project 2' 
                }];
              
                $scope.openEntityPage = function(event) {
                    console.log('click', event);
                };
            },
            compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
                return {
                    pre: function preLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
                             function init() {
                 element.append(buildTree(scope.treeObject));

                 element.find('.fa').bind('click', function() {
                     $(this).toggleClass('close-level');
                     $(this).next().find('> div').slideToggle(400);
                 });
             }

             function buildTree(treeObject) {
                 var counter;
                 var div = angular.element('<div>');
                 var textDiv;
                 /* must create like a another div because passed value via reference */
                 /* when we change text() it change it in result */

                 for (counter = 0; counter < treeObject.length; counter = counter + 1) {
                     textDiv = angular.element('<div>');
                     if('id_project' in treeObject[counter]){ //project
                         textDiv.attr('ng-entity-type', 'project');
                         textDiv.attr('ng-id', treeObject[counter].id_project);
                     } else { // task
                         textDiv.attr('ng-entity-type', 'task');
                         textDiv.attr('ng-id', treeObject[counter].id);
                     }
                     textDiv.attr('ng-click', 'openEntityPage($event)');

                     textDiv.text(treeObject[counter].name);
                     div.append(textDiv);
                     if ('childs' in treeObject[counter]) {
                         // div.prepend('<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>');
                         textDiv.prepend('<i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>');
                         textDiv.append(buildTree(treeObject[counter].childs));
                     }
                 }
                 return div;
             }
                    },
                    post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {}
                }
            }
        };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="hierarchyTree">
</div>
```

Рабочий пример:
https://plnkr.co/edit/Zwb1qhRcndOBB9ABlPUp?p=preview

Comment: добавь [mcve], чтобы можно было запустить и сразу увидеть, что происходит

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Не могу сказать почему не сработало внутри `pre`, возможно слишком поздно срабатывает.</strike>

Изменения атрибутов нужно делать непосредственно в функции `compile`, кроме того параметр `element` указывает на элемент директивы, в данном случае это элемент `<hierarchy-tree>`, для добавления атрибутов дочерним элементам, нужно их выбрать, например с помощью функции `children`

Пример:

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('hierarchyTree', function() {
    return {
      template: `
        <div id="1">Element1</div>
        <div id="2">Element2</div>
        {{vm.clicked}}
      `,
      controller: function() {
        var vm = this;
        vm.click = function(e) {
          vm.clicked = `${e.target.id} was clicked.`;
        };
      },
      controllerAs: 'vm',
      compile: function(elems, attrs, tr) {
        elems.children().attr('ng-click', 'vm.click($event)');
        return {
          pre: function(scope, elem, attrs) {},
          post: function() {}
        };
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <hierarchy-tree></hierarchy-tree>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:** на этапе выполнения функции `prelink` нет смысла добавлять в шаблон директивы, потому что шаблон **уже** скомпилирован.

В качестве решения можно добавлять обработчики событий вручную в скрипте с помощью функций `click`, `on`.

Возможно в данном случае вместо построения html в функциях `pre-/post-link` хватит использования шаблона.

```js
angular.module('example', [])
  .controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.openEntityPage = function(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('event');
    };

    $scope.allProjects = [{
      name: 'Project 1',
      childs: [{
        name: 'Task 1',
        childs: [{
          name: 'Task 1.1'
        }, {
          name: 'Task 1.2'
        }]
      }, {
        name: 'Task 2'
      }, {
        name: 'Task 3'
      }]
    }, {
      name: 'Project 2'
    }];
  })


angular.module('example')
  .directive('hierarchyTree', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'ctrl',
      templateUrl: 'tree.html',
      compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
        return {
          pre: function preLink(scope, element, iAttrs, controller) {
            scope.toggle = function(event) {
              event.stopPropagation();
              angular.element(event.target).toggleClass('close-level')
                             .next().find('> div').slideToggle(400);
            }
          },
          post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {}
        }
      }
    };
  });
```

```css
hierarchy-tree {
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid #333;
}
hierarchy-tree > div > div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
hierarchy-tree > div > div > div > div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
hierarchy-tree > div > div > div > div > div > div {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.5/angular.js"></script>

<div ng-app="example">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    {{value}}
    <hierarchy-tree treeObject="allProjects"></hierarchy-tree>
  </div>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree.html">
    <div ng-entity-type="task" ng-click="openEntityPage($event)" ng-repeat="item in allProjects">
      <i ng-if="item.childs" ng-click="toggle($event)" class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>{{item.name}}
      <div ng-if="item.childs" ng-init="allProjects=item.childs" ng-include="'tree.html'"></div>
    </div>
  </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Шаблон заранее не известен
      template: `
        <div id="1">Element1</div>
        <div id="2">Element2</div>
он может быть бесконечно вложенный как
<div id="1">Element1
<div id="11">Element 1 1
<div id="111">Element 111</div>
</div>
</div>
И создание этой структуры я делаю в 'prelink'

Comment: @NikolayPodolnyy, не принципиально, здесь пример ровно такой, какой был в вопросе. Важен лишь подход, который тут используется

Comment: Не совсем так, мне нужно в момент создания вешать на узел 2 вещи
 - атрибут
 - директиву ng-click

Comment: @NikolayPodolnyy, все равно не вижу проблемы, в каком именно месте решение из вопроса не подходит?

Comment: Подскажи как добавить рабочий пример как в твоем ответе выше  - я приведу пример

Comment: @NikolayPodolnyy, под вопросом есть кнопка "править" при нажатии ее вопрос перейдет в режим редактирования, и сверху в редакторе будет кнопка `<>` (Фрагмент кода на JS/HTML/CSS Ctrl+M)

Comment: Добавил в вопрос ссылку на рабочий пример

Comment: @NikolayPodolnyy, обновил ответ